# slice(which.max()) with condition

Tags: r, slice

I have the following dataset:

```
ID, diff

1  -40

1  -21

1  -5

1  1

1  6

1  7

...
```

ID variable has values 1,2,3,4,5,... while diff is a numeric variable. Now, from the dataset, for each ID I want to extract the row with a diff that is closest to zero AND is negative. So, I want the row with the highest negative value of diff. In the dataset above, for ID 1 I want to extract 3 rows with values (1 -5).

The following code can extract rows where the absolute value is closest to 0:

```
library(dplyr)

dataset22 = dataset1 %>%  group_by(ID) %>% slice(which.min(abs(diff)))
```

How can I extract the row with a negative number that is closest to zero?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a `filter` before the `slice`: `filter(diff <= 0)` which would also remove all IDs with diff only larger than 0...

Comment: Or `max(diff[which(diff<=0)])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 diff = c(-40, -21, -5, 1, 6, 7))

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(diff < 0) %>%
  summarise(min_negative_diff = max(diff))

#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>      ID min_negative_diff
#>   <dbl>             <dbl>
#> 1     1                -5
```